# Is there an "on mount" hook for fuse?

Tags: fuse

Say I want to make an app to sync my music to Cyanogenmod.

I would like to examine all mounted volumes (assuming I enabled USB debugging on my Cyanogen driven device), then I can just examine the Music folder and the ~/Music folder.

So, I'm looking for a way to fire a "new device mounted" event instead of having to poll.

Comment: It seems there isn't.  If someone doesn't come back with one, I'll post a libudev solution instead after some time.

Comment: I think you should look at udisk, not fuse ;)

Comment: moving this to pygi seems like the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/5111493/486399